# Kendo UI MVC Grid - Why doesn't the ClientDetailTemplate read the data?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

So I'm trying to do is an hierarchy grid from Kendo UI MVC. I'm listing some employees and their number of pending requests. Then, for each employee there is a child grid listing their pending requests. However, for some reason I still didn't figure it out (I'm using ajax on the datasource, yes), the Read Action from the child grid doesn't go to the controller.

Here is the code of my grid:

```
 <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="demo-section" style="width:100%">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<WorkTimeManager.Presentation.Models.ReqAdminViewModel>()
      .Name("requests")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(req => req.EmployeeName).Title("Employee Name").Width(30);
          columns.Bound(req => req.NumPendingRequests).Title ("# Pending Request").Width(15);
      })
      .Pageable()

      .Selectable(selectable =>
      {
          selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single);
          selectable.Type(GridSelectionType.Row);
      })
      .Sortable(sortable =>
      {
          sortable.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn);
      })
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Read(read => read.Action("AdminEmployees_Read", "Request")))        
          .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
        )
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<script id="template" type="text/kendo">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<WorkTimeManager.Presentation.Models.RequestViewModel>()
            .Name("requests_#=EmployeeID#") // template expression, to be evaluated in the master context
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
            columns.Bound(req => req.RequestType).Title("Request Type").Width(25);
            columns.Bound(req => req.Justification).Title("Justification").Width(300);
            columns.Bound(req => req.DateRequested).Title("Date Requested").Width(75);
            columns.Bound(req => req.PeriodRequested).Title("Period Requested").Width(150);
            })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(10)
                .Read(read => read.Action("AdminPendingRequests_Read", "Request", new { employeeID = "#=EmployeeID#" }))
            )
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .ToClientTemplate()
    )
</script>
```

The read actions from the controller:

```
  public ActionResult AdminEmployees_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            List<Business.Employee> employees = Business.EmployeeBusiness.GetAllActiveEmployees();
            List<Business.Absence> absences = Business.AbsenceBusiness.GetAllPendingAbsences();
            List<Business.AdditionalHoursRequest> additionalHours = Business.AdditionalHoursRequestBusiness.GetAllPendingRequests();
            List<Business.CompensationDayRequest> compensationDays = Business.CompensationDayRequestBusiness.GetAllPendingRequests();
            List<Business.ErrorCorrectionRequest> errorCorrections = Business.ErrorCorrectionRequestBusiness.GetAllPendingRequests();
            List<Business.EmployeeVacationDay> vacationDays = Business.EmployeeVacationDayBusiness.GetAllPendingVacationDays();
            List<ReqAdminViewModel> reqAdminEmpList = CreateViewModelList(employees,absences,additionalHours,compensationDays,errorCorrections,vacationDays);

            DataSourceResult result = reqAdminEmpList.ToDataSourceResult(request, reqAdminViewModel => new ReqAdminViewModel
            {
                EmployeeName = reqAdminViewModel.EmployeeName,
                NumPendingRequests = reqAdminViewModel.NumPendingRequests
            });
            return Json(result);
        }

public ActionResult AdminPendingRequests_Read(int employeeID, [DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
       {
           //Getting Pending Requests from Database
           List<Business.CompensationDayRequest> pendingCDR = Business.CompensationDayRequestBusiness.GetPendingCompensationDayRequestByEmployee(employeeID);
           List<Business.AdditionalHoursRequest> pendingAHR = Business.AdditionalHoursRequestBusiness.GetPendingAdditionalHoursRequestsByEmployeeID(employeeID);
           List<Business.EmployeeVacationDay> pendingEVD = Business.EmployeeVacationDayBusiness.GetPendingVacationDayByEmployeeID(employeeID);
           List<Business.ErrorCorrectionRequest> pendingECR = Business.ErrorCorrectionRequestBusiness.GetPendingErrorCorrectionRequestsByEmployeeID(employeeID);
           List<Business.Absence> pendingABS = Business.AbsenceBusiness.GetPendingRequestsByEmployee(employeeID);

           List<Object> orderedRequests = GetOrderedRequests(GetDateTimeList(pendingABS, pendingAHR, pendingCDR, pendingECR, pendingEVD), pendingABS, pendingAHR, pendingCDR, pendingECR, pendingEVD); //Ordering Requests by Date Requested
           List<RequestViewModel> requestList = CreateRequestList(orderedRequests); //Create Request View Model List

           DataSourceResult result = requestList.ToDataSourceResult(request, requestListViewModel => new RequestViewModel
           {
               RequestID = requestListViewModel.RequestID,
               RequestType = requestListViewModel.RequestType,
               Justification = requestListViewModel.Justification,
               DateRequested = requestListViewModel.DateRequested,
               PeriodRequested = requestListViewModel.PeriodRequested,
               RequestStatus = requestListViewModel.RequestStatus
           });
           return Json(result);
       }
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Thanks for the help! ;)

Comment: from quickly looking at this you don't actually seem to be passing back the `EmployeeID`  only the name and the pending requests. I suspect if you add in the `EmployeeID` it will start working. If you run fiddler what does the request look like for the details grid. is it just appending employeeID= ?

Comment: True, forgot about that. Added  columns.Bound(req => req.EmployeeID).Title("ID").Width(10); in the main grid and  EmployeeID = reqAdminViewModel.EmployeeID, in the DataSourceResult, the IDs on the table are correct, however, it still doesn't work. I put a breakpoint in the AdminPendingRequests_Read and it doesn't go there... :/

Comment: So if you run fiddler to see what happens when it tries to call the method what is it doing? i.e. are you getting a 404 error

Comment: No, I don't get any error... It called the AdminEmployee_read but it didn't say anything about the AdminPendingRequests_Read

Comment: try moving the employeeID parameter after the DataSourceRequest parameter in your second adminpending read action.

Comment: try putting the template above the main grid. All the examples seem to show it that way round rather than the other way round. Other than seeing a sample project it will be difficult to tell what the issue is.